# Where to find .htaccess file in my Xampp localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a simple problem here. I'm a beginner in using php and apache. Actually I want to modify some config in my .htaccess but i cant find in. Can anyone tell me where is it located. TIA.

Comment: .htaccess would go in each project. Are you confusing it with php or apache settings?

Answer (score 21):

`.htaccess` sets directory specific settings and it can go in **each web directory** as needed to change settings.

Some server packages will include a blank/basic one in the root www dir.

If XAMPP doesn't include one, just create a text file and name it `.htaccess` and edit it however you need.

Comment: Hi, checked my www folder and its empty.

Comment: in that case see my third sentence

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Depends on exactly how you have it set up, but it should be in the web dir - If I'm remembering correctly, yes that is htdocs by default.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion around this. `.htaccess` are a custom configuration files and you can have as many as you want (or none at all) wherever you need below web server's document root; there's absolutely no need to have a single file in project's root.

Answer (score 4):

`.htaccess` includes in your project like if you're working on wordpress and whatever you named the folder, just enter that folder and search it you may find it.

here you may see

[image: screenshot of directory structure]

Answer (score 2):

see .htaccess file is usually present in your C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress if you are in windows or /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress if you are on linux or mac if you can't find it simply...
( for Windows )
enable show hidden files in file manager...
(for linux)
open terminal and type...

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress
sudo ls -a
```

here it will show if it is present and if not simply make a direcroy...

```
sudo touch .htaccess
```

and paste the .htaccess you will see at wordpress by typing...

```
sudo gedit .htaccess
```

and here paste the following...

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and you're ready to go...
Hope your issue is resolved...
Thank You have a nice day...   :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one **.htaccess** file in the **XAMPP's htdocs** folder which you can customize or use as you want.